# Javascript dynamically print in the script tag

Tags: javascript

How do I dynamically create JavaScript? The problem is, I have a variable and want it to be resolved as a value in the next script tag but I cannot find how.. For example:

```
chartData = chartData + "['"+record["appname"]+", '"+record["CurrentConnections"]+"'], ";
```

chartdata is a variable that basically is the value that is correct format for the following code to display a chart:

```
<script>
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          // !!!!NEED VALUE TO BE RESOLVED HERE!!!!
               ]);
            var options = {
            title: '<?php echo "$server"; ?>',
            is3D: true
        };
       var chart = new       google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

So in the place where !!!!NEED VALUE TO BE RESOLVED HERE!!!! comment is I want it so the script would appear as..

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['xxx', '1'], ['yyy', '13'], ['zzz', '233']
  ]);
```

This would then display the chart. I can do this statically but I want it to get it from a variable. If I use PHP and echo it will print the JavaScript how I want it but in this particular case I cannot use PHP.

or how do I loop inside the script tag to make it assume it is like this.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Consider `var arr = [], a = 'xxx', b = '1'; arr.push([a, b]); arr; // [['xxx', '1']]`

Comment: Perhaps [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) could help?

Comment: also you are missing a `'`(single quote) in chartData

Comment: I tried eval(). all it does is writes eval(...). How exactly do I need to write eval?

Answer (score 0):

eval is used like this:

```
var myJS = "console.log('test')";
eval(myJS);
```

I think it should help.

Comment: I am going to experiment with it. I did get the result, but graph still not being drawn.

Answer (score 0):

I pass variables in through QueryString parameters.

```
<script src="script.js?key=value"></script>
```

You can use a function that gets the current running script's params

```
function getScriptParameter(key, default_) {
    //get the query string items for the current script
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var index = scripts.length - 1;
    var myScript = scripts[index];
        if (default_ == null) default_ = "";
            key = key.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + key + "=([^&#]*)");
    var qs = regex.exec(myScript.src);
        if (qs == null)
            return default_;
        else
            return qs[1];
}
```